# Reducing formula with factorials

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm still a beginner working with factorials so, how should I reduce this formula i.e(cancel some member to make numbers smaller) ?

$$\dfrac{(n^2)!}{4!(n^2 - 4)!\cdot Q}$$

Comment: If you say $y=n^2$ then your formula becomes $$\frac{y!}{4!\cdot(y-4)!\cdot Q}.$$  Is it easier to see how to simplify that formula?

Comment: Hint: $$(n^2)! = \prod_{i=0}^{n^2-1} (n^2-i)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$$(n^2)! = n^2 (n^2 - 1)(n^2 - 2)(n^2 - 3) (n^2 - 4)!$$

So your formula can be reduced to

$$\frac{n^2 (n^2 - 1)(n^2 - 2)(n^2 - 3)}{24Q}$$